# how to display Textbox values in the crystal reports?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i have a text box in the front end i want to display this textBox value along with my data table in `CRYSTAL REPORT VIEWER`. I have displayed data table value successfully , but found some hurdles to display textBox values. I am using Web Application(c#). Pls Help..

Thanks in Advance..

this is my code-

```
  protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument rdt = new ReportDocument();
    EmpDetail emp1 = new EmpDetail();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "EmpDataTable";
    dt = putEmployeeDetails();
    emp1.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
    rdt.Load(Server.MapPath("Emp.rpt"));
    rdt.SetDataSource(emp1);
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc=rdt;
    doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["display1"].Text = "sdfsdf";
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdt;
}
```

for this am getting error at
     doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["display1"].Text = "sdfsdf";
as "Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"

Comment: do you have correct FormulaFields Name(display1)? have you placed/draged your textbox to the report designer?

Comment: Yes Ashmini i did the same. and cofirmed in property window also as the formmula field's "name" is "dislay1"

Comment: if i give that formula field's name as "display" its taking "display1" in property window. and if i use doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["display"].Text = TextBox1.text; then it shows error as- "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula. Details: errorKind Error in File Emp {D4A93128-EF26-48C9-AD2C-9599D92DF8A4}.rpt: Error in formula display: 'ttt' The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula. Details: errorKind" Pls Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your query and everything and fill in Dataset.

```
Dim SPATH As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Aqeel\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PHARMA\PHARMA"
SPATH += "\Combinedrp.rpt"
RPT.Load(SPATH)
RPT.SetDataSource(DS2)
Dim firstName = RPT.ParameterFields("@dt1")
firstName.CurrentValues.AddValue(TextBox1.Text)
firstName.HasCurrentValue = True

Dim lastName = RPT.ParameterFields("@dt2")
lastName.CurrentValues.AddValue(TextBox2.Text)
lastName.HasCurrentValue = True
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPT
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument doc=load your document;
doc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["formulafieldname"].Text = "'your text here";
```

please go through this link:[textbox to Crystal Report](http://forums.asp.net/t/1647341.aspx/1)

and also visit here for more about Crystal report:[Crystal Reports in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-Crystal-Reports.aspx)

Comment: i am using Text object. I have to bind the textBox data to it.

Comment: when you create a formula fields and place it on a report, you will have a ReportDocument.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create parameters in your crystal report then pass your text to those parameters.

Comment: but how to bind that to text Object??

Comment: you can just drag/drop the parameter fields onto the report canvas or drag/drop them directly into text objects